# Basement Wall - Proper wall material

Tags: basement

I have one unfinished room in my basement which holds the furnace and hot water tank, and I use it as a workshop and gym. I have block foundation and the concrete walls have this foam board mounted to it with these 1x2's it seems. My basement has been dry since I moved here 2 years ago (eastern Ontario, Canada).

I would like to cover this insulation in order to protect it from getting damaged, and I would possibly like to hang things from the wall. I am thinking plywood of some sort/thickness. My questions are as follows:

1. What is the best way to mount some sort of protection to act as a wall? What is the best material and thickness?
2. Should I screw into the block foundation or just mount it on the 1x2?
3. Should I add anything to the wall before mounting the plywood? *vapour barrier?*

I would appreciate any assistance or recommendations, I look forward to contributing to this community.

Photos here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhBAU.jpg

**My pictures show no vapour barrier in the ceiling joists which I added after the photo was taken**

Comment: It looks like your 1x2’s are on the surface of the insulation, how are they attached to the wall? The wiring running down the 1x2 would need to be moved, I could see plywood working if those strips are securely anchored to the wall and the plywood rests on the floor you may need to change the wiring method because those boxes will be two deep and a shallow box won’t be large enough to allow splices.  I have done this with J boxes at the top of the wall with decorative covers that can be removed , not sure if this is allowed in Canada.

Comment: They are screwed through the insulation and into the cement. Since they are only 1x3's I can't imagine they are that strong. Perhaps just sheets of plywood between them?

Comment: The problem without the furring strip there would not be enough room for your electrical a device box is 1-1/2” deep and this is not deep enough for splices, I have used shallow boxes and spliced at the ceiling joist bay.  If you do not plan on hanging heavy things off the plywood the 1x3 would be a good attachment point let the bottom sheet rest on the slab or place something between the wood and slab so it can not absorb moisture. I use left over shingles, tarpaper or sill seal (foam designed to go between the wall bottom plate and the concrete.

Comment: It depends on what you plan to hang on the wall. The wood looks more like a furring strip, maybe 4-6mm, not 19mm like a 1x2. That's too thin to hold any weight, especially with only 3 screws in each board. I'd use minimum 1/2-3/4" (12-19mm) plywood, spaced out with more furring strips, then screwed into the concrete wall. Leave a 1/4" (4-6mm) gap at the bottom to prevent wicking moisture into the plywood. If you want to hang heavier loads, frame out & attach a wall with appropriate (2x4 or 2x6) studs instead of just plywood.

Comment: Thanks Eric, so add more strips and attach 3/4" on top of them but screw through them into the concrete wall? Just so I understand? I'm more interested in lighter loads and protecting the insulation/wall from getting hit and falling apart.  Is there any point is adding more insulation in the gaps that will be created behind the plywood?